# Python 3 error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written code to solve a problem.

Here is My Code:

```
t=int(input())
print("")
while(t):
    s=0
    n=int(input())
    for i in range(n):
        no=int(input())
        s=s+no
    if s%n==0:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
    print("")
    t-=1
```

When I run it on the OS X terminal, it works fine. But when I run it on `IDEone` or Submit it as a solution, it gives an error on `line 5`:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I am unsure of what the problem is.

Comment: Then maybe you should check the result from `input` before trying to convert it to an `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not handling if the user enters nothing, in other words empty string

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

You can use [a variety of techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) to more robustly accept input from the user.